# Wrong table rendering in mails in Outlook 2016

Tags: html, css, email, ms-office, outlook-2016

we have a problem with rendering a mail element correctly in Outlook 2016. It works correctly in Outlook 2013 and other mail clients (and of course the browser preview), but we don´t have any clue how to fix this rendering issue for Outlook 2016.

The layout idea of this element is to have a centered white background box with 600px width that should take the content. First element in the top left corner of this "content box" should be a white text in a black box. The width of this black background box should be (at least nearly) the same as the text length (and of course, this text is just a few words in one line normally).

While all mail clients shorten the size of the black background box to the size of the text string, Outlook 2016 shows this box at at ~3/4 of the element´s width (600px), even if I just use one letter as text.

Here is a snippet:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
<![endif]-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="max-width:600px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width: 600px;">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#000000" align="left" style="width: 0px; font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight: 500; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 5px 10px;">Boxcontent</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

As you can see, we even repeat some of the styling tags.
We use this code in other places too (in different contexts) without the rendering issues, but were not able to identify what causes the width of the black background box to be resized like this in Outlook 2016.

Thank you very much in advance for any hints!

Joerg

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the style="max-width:600px;" for style="min-width:600px;"